# g_array_sort not working on string

Tags: c, arrays, string, glib

How using **g_array_sort** for strings in C?
My code using compare string but I'cant get data

```
int porownanie(gpointer a, gpointer b)
 {
 char *str_a = (char *)a; char *str_b = (char *)b; 
  printf("[%s:%s]=%d\n",str_a,str_b,g_ascii_strcasecmp(str_a,str_b));  
 return strcmp(str_a,str_b);
 }
```

main function

```
GArray* t = g_array_new(FALSE, FALSE, sizeof(char*));
char* a = "a", *b = "c", *c = "d"....
g_array_append_val(t, a);....

prt(t);printf("Sortujemy\n"); g_array_sort(t, (GCompareFunc)porownanie);
prt(t); printf("Porownanie %d\n",porownanie((char *)"a",(char *)"b"));
```

I get :

```
Tablica: b a f c d  
[z_:t_]=6 
[v_:x_]=-2 
[|_:v_]=6 
[|_:x_]=4
[t_:v_]=-2 
[z_:v_]=4 
[z_:x_]=2 
[z_:|_]=-2 
Tablica: a c d b f 
[a:b]=-1 Porownanie -1
```

I'm not get char* from g_aray_sort, I get random data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort function receives a pointer to the item to be sorted, not the value itself.  You need something like

```
int porownanie(gpointer a, gpointer b)
{
  char **str_a = (char **)a; char **str_b = (char **)b; 
  printf("[%s:%s]=%d\n",*str_a,*str_b,g_ascii_strcasecmp(*str_a,*str_b));  
  return strcmp(*str_a,*str_b);
}
```

FWIW, the rationale here is that the items could be anything, including large structs that you don't really want to copy around… think about what would happen if you had an array of

```
struct Foo {
  guint8 input_buffer[4096];
  guint8 output_buffer[4096];
}
```

In fact, for strings you would generally use a GPtrArray, not a GArray.  The sort function still requires char** arguments (because a GPtrArray is really just a convenience API around GArray), but it assumes values are `sizeof(void*)` and makes the API a bit easier to use.